# Preventing user access to page without login not working

Tags: php

When I try to login it doesn't allow me to, but when I take it out, it allows me to but even when I logout it still allows me on the page?

I know the problematic area is the PHP code in the welcome.php

Login.php:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="connection.php">
        <td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
        <td width="78">Username</td>
        <td width="6">:</td>
        <td width="294">
            <input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername">
        </td>
        Password: 
        <input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword">
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Connection.php:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    $host="localhost"; // Host name 
    $username="root"; // Mysql username 
    $password=""; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="v2"; // Database name 
    $tbl_name="members"; // Table name 

    // Connect to server and select databse.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    // Define $myusername and $mypassword 
    $myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
    $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

    // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
    $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
    $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
    $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";                            
    $result=mysql_query($sql);

    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if($count==1){
        // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "welcome.php"
        $_SESSION["myusername"];
        $_SESSION["mypassword"];
        header("location:welcome.php");
    }
    else {
        echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    }
    ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Welcome.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["myusername"])){
        header("location:login.php");
    }
?>

<html>
<body>
    You have successfully logged in!
    <br>
    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First comment: Switch to PDO or MySQLi. MySQL is deprecated and gone as of PHP 7!

Comment: `welcome.php` should `exit()` after it calls `header()`. Also, check your logs and make sure you're not getting a `Headers already sent` warning.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to avoid direct access to super globals. You could use the php 'filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username'); instead. Also remember to encrypt your password too. Perhaps you encrypted the passwords in to table and failed to decrypt it on 'select' query...go through it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change to

```
  // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "welcome.php"
 $_SESSION["myusername"]=$myusername;
 $_SESSION["mypassword"]=$mypassword;
```

for to work this `if(!isset($_SESSION["myusername"]))`